# Using multiple NOT IN statements with Python

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements

I need to URLs with three specific specific substrings out of a loop. The following code worked, but I am sure there's a more elegant way to do it:

```
for node in soup.findAll('loc'):
    url = node.text.encode("utf-8")
    if "/store/" not in url and "/cell-phones/" not in url and "/accessories/" not in url:
        objlist.loc.append(url) 
    else:
        continue
```

Thank you!

Comment: You can use  the builtin function all

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
url = node.text.encode("utf-8")    
sub_strings = ['/store','/cell-phones/','accessories']

if not any(x in url for x in sub_strings):
    objlist.loc.append(url)
else:
    continue
```

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any):

`any` returns True if any element of the iterable is true. If the iterable is empty, return False. Equivalent to:

```
def any(iterable):
    for element in iterable:
        if element:
            return True
    return False
```

Comment: Boom. Thanks, Ian!

Comment: You could also not apply the de Morgan transformation and do `all(x not in url for x in sub_strings)`.